# AngularStrap: typeahead not works

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I tried the simplest possible AngularStrap typeahead [example](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/typeaheads), but nothing shows when I type in the input box.

Please advice..

**Edit:** My JSFiddle [code](https://jsfiddle.net/hg2y5k38/)

Angular: v1.4.2

AngularStrap: v2.2.4

jQuery: v2.1.4

Bootstrap v3.3.5

Comment: please separate your code into just the part you need help with, then put the code into the page and you will be able to run it in an inline interactive demo by pressing ctrl (or command) + M (like jsfiddle or Codepen but onsite so it stays with the site over time), this way it can be debugged and will be most likely solved for you. Its very overwhelming when you see a hope webpage full of markup with scripts that point to files which are relative to the local filesystem of your server (not viewable from the gist link to Github provided)

Comment: @AlphaG33k I added link to my  jsfiddle code